# How to extract individual elements from a list of selector objects?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

> i am Trying to print the name of the product from a website by taking all the product element and iterating over ecah element.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    result = response.xpath("//div[@class = 's-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row']")

    for item in result:
        for product in item.xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']"):
            print(product.xpath("//h2/a/span/text()").extract())
```

> but it is not giving individually, it is printing all at once. And while printing the name of an individual it is printing all the names in the list.
> here is the output of the above code.

```
   ['Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 70 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Large, 88 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers M
onthly Box Pack, Medium, 108 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Large (Pack of 168)', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 64 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants,
 Medium, 76 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, XL, 56 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, New Born, 72 Count', 'Huggies Wonder Pants, Small Size Diapers, 86 Count', 'M
amyPoko Pants Standard Diapers, Small (Pack of 46)', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 64 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Small, 86 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly
Box Packs, X-Large, 112 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, XX-Large, 28 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Medium, 50 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly Box Pack, Me
dium, 152 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Medium, 108 Count', 'Pampers Baby Dry Pants Diapers Monthly Mega Box, Large, 128 Count', 'Pam
pers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 70 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 54 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, XXL, 30 Count', 'Pamp
ers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, XL, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Large, 88 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants D
iapers, Large, 44 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 50 Count', 'Supples Baby Pants Diapers, Medium, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diape
rs, XXL, 30 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers - 62 Pieces (Medium)', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Large , 42 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 44 Count', 'Pamp
ers Diaper Pants, New Baby, 86 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, XL, 36 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Small, 36 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Small,
 58 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, New Born, 66 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, XXL , 16 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Medium (Pack of
200)', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Extra Large, 34 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Small, 56 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 38 Count', 'Pam
pers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 50 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 16 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 46 Count',
'Pampers New Diaper Pants, XXXL, 7 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Extra Large (Pack of 136)', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Large (P
ack of 168)', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Large, 30 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly Box Pack, Small, 172 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Medium, 28
 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, New Born, 20 Count', 'Pampers Baby Dry Diaper Pants, Large (60 Count)', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Small, 20 Count', 'Pampers Pre
mium Care Pants Diapers, XL, 24 Count', 'Accupressure for Babies : Pamper your toddler with a gentle massage! (New Mom  Series)', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers
, Large, 17 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 24 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 21 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super
Value Box, Small (Pack of 224)', 'Pampers Splashers Disposable Swim Pants Diapers, Large, 11 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, Medium, 90 Count', 'Pampers Active
 Baby Diapers, New Born, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Super Value box pack, XL, 108 Count', 'Huggies Wonder Pants, Large Size Diapers, 64 Count', 'Pampers Active
 Baby Diapers, Large, 50 Count']
```

.............
.............
(same list is being printed for 60 times)
.............
.............

```
 ['Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 70 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Large, 88 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Medium, 108 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Large (Pack of 168)', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 64 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants,
 Medium, 76 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, XL, 56 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, New Born, 72 Count', 'Huggies Wonder Pants, Small Size Diapers, 86 Count', 'MamyPoko Pants Standard Diapers, Small (Pack of 46)', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 64 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Small, 86 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly
Box Packs, X-Large, 112 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, XX-Large, 28 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Medium, 50 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly Box Pack, Me
dium, 152 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Medium, 108 Count', 'Pampers Baby Dry Pants Diapers Monthly Mega Box, Large, 128 Count', 'Pam
pers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 70 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 54 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, XXL, 30 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, XL, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers Monthly Box Pack, Large, 88 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Large, 44 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 50 Count', 'Supples Baby Pants Diapers, Medium, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, XXL, 30 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers - 62 Pieces (Medium)', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Large , 42 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Large, 44 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, New Baby, 86 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, XL, 36 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Small, 36 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants, Small,58 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, New Born, 66 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, XXL , 16 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Medium (Pack of
200)', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Extra Large, 34 Count', 'Pampers New Diapers Pants, Small, 56 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 38 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 50 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Medium, 16 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 46 Count',
'Pampers New Diaper Pants, XXXL, 7 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Extra Large (Pack of 136)', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants Super Value Box, Large (P
ack of 168)', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Large, 30 Count', 'Pampers Diaper Pants Monthly Box Pack, Small, 172 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Medium, 28
 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, New Born, 20 Count', 'Pampers Baby Dry Diaper Pants, Large (60 Count)', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants, Small, 20 Count', 'Pampers Pre
mium Care Pants Diapers, XL, 24 Count', 'Accupressure for Babies : Pamper your toddler with a gentle massage! (New Mom  Series)', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Large, 17 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, New Born, 24 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Pants Diapers, Small, 21 Count', 'Pampers New Diaper Pants SuperValue Box, Small (Pack of 224)', 'Pampers Splashers Disposable Swim Pants Diapers, Large, 11 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, Medium, 90 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, New Born, 72 Count', 'Pampers Premium Care Super Value box pack, XL, 108 Count', 'Huggies Wonder Pants, Large Size Diapers, 64 Count', 'Pampers Active Baby Diapers, Large, 50 Count']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have you add `.` in your xpath (`.//h2/a/span/text()`) to get individual value and also use `get()` methot which returns first value instead of using `extract()` which retunrs list of values

```py
 for item in result:
        for product in item.xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']"):
            print(product.xpath(".//h2/a/span/text()").get())
```